# How to sum cost using 2 values as upper and lower limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently making a planner for a game that i'm playing. But i am currently stuck in my 'level cost calculator'.

[image: Level Cost Calculator]

In 'Database' table, it contains the EXP needed to level up on each level, 1 to 2 requires 100 EXP, 2 to 3 requires 117 EXP and so on. Manually, to calculate the EXP i need from level 3 to 18 i have to use SUM(NN38:NN53), but i don't know the function that i have to use so i can automatically calculate the EXP required just by changing 'Current Level' and 'Target Level' value.

I have been doing a very basic excel, and didnt get any kind of excel course, so honestly i dont really understand even if i check each of functions' descriptions.

Pardon me for my (probably) bad explanation, english is not my first language and i am not a programmer in any way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5qyB.png

I tried to add another column calculate them separately, using

> 

```
=IF($NI$41<=NM36,IF($NK$41>=NM36,NN36,0),0)
```

then i fill it down then sum it, but it is very tedious and ineffective as i have to do the same for different characters

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in your example (current level = 3, target = 18), the total should be everything from NN38 to NN52. Since your levels are in order, you should be able to do `=SUM(OFFSET(NN35, NI41, 0):OFFSET(NN35, NK41 - 1, 0) )`.

Comment: The function works very well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the followings, the formulas posted do not use volatile functions and hence it will not recalculate anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes! That said formulas are:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C5</kbd>

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(B3,E3:E22,F3:F22):XLOOKUP(C3,E3:E22,F3:F22))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell <kbd>C6</kbd>

```
=SUM(INDEX(F3:F22,MATCH(B3,E3:E22,0)):INDEX(F3:F22,MATCH(C3,E3:E22,0)))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell <kbd>C7</kbd>

```
=SUM(TAKE(DROP(F3:F22,B3-1),C3-(B3-1)))
```

---

However, if you want to exclude the current level then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C5</kbd>

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(B3+1,E3:E22,F3:F22):XLOOKUP(C3,E3:E22,F3:F22))
```

---

• Or, in cell <kbd>C6</kbd>

```
=SUM(INDEX(F3:F22,MATCH(B3+1,E3:E22,0)):INDEX(F3:F22,MATCH(C3,E3:E22,0)))
```

---

• Or, in cell <kbd>C7</kbd>

```
=SUM(TAKE(DROP(F3:F22,B3),C3-B3))
```

---

Comment: Thank you sir, but sadly i can only use the second option since i'm still using excel 2019, XLOOKUP, TAKE and DROP function is not yet available. But i will try to test it if i had a chance to export my file into spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Since your values are a mathematical series with the increment  of 17, this formula gives the sum:

`=(17*(NI41+NK41)+149)*(NK41-NI41)/2`

Comment: A good input sir, however what i displayed is only a portion of the whole level range. Along with the level raise, the increments also changed as well at some points, so this formula is pretty limited in application.

Regardless, Thank You